# Forward request from one domain to another without changing the URL in browser

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

i am trying to add a worker which will redirect/forward the request from https://test1.com to https://test2.com

```
const redirectHttpCode = 301
const targetUrl = "https://test2.com"
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
async function handleRequest(request) {
  if (targetUrl) {
    return Response.redirect(targetUrl, redirectHttpCode)
  }
  return fetch(request)
}
```

the route configured as `*test1.com/*` to above worker

with this worker if i try to access https://test1.com it redirects the request to https://test2.com and changes the URL in browser with status code 301 as expected.

is it possible to forward/redirect the request from https://test1.com to https://test2.com without changing the URL in the browser or User getting to know there is a redirection happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the example [Respond with another site](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/respond-with-another-site), you need to call `respondWith` with the answer of the final website. Given `respondWith` can handle either a `Response` or a promise that will eventually unfold into a response,  the simplest case is returning a fetch call:

```
async function handleEvent(event) {
  event.respondWith(fetch('https://www.test2.com'))
}
```

In which case you would be connecting two streams, without awaiting for `test2` whatsoever.

When the use case involves modifying the actual response (as in the example: [Alter Headers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/alter-headers)), you'll need to await the outcome of fetch, and perform any modification on a clone of it, because the former is inmutable.

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.test2.com'),
        modifiedResponse = new Response(response.body, response);

  modifiedResponse.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  return modifiedResponse;
}

async function handleEvent(event) {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
}
```

---

**Errata 2022-02-21**

The original answer said you could clone the response to get one with mutable headers. This is wrong. Doing

```
    modifiedResponse = response.clone();
```

Gets you a clone whose headers are just as inmutable as the original. The right way is to use the `Response` constructor

```
    modifiedResponse = new Response(response.body, response);
```